# Catch ANY error of streaming video (VLC ActiveX)

Tags: c#, .net, events, activex, vlc

I have investigated all methods we have to use via C# code or JavaScript of VLC Player ActiveX and I cannot see any existing or working methods to help to get info if there is ANY error of playing of some streaming video.

I have used `Playing` property to see what does it show when connection to internet is turned off during playing and it shows always `true`. :(   wow!

To make it clear I just need to control any streaming errors of VLC Player ActiveX in order to re-start streaming if there is an error automatically but it seems that all API is done to accept direct user input only.

This link http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC does't help.

My question: Is there ANY method/property that indicate about streaming video error?

Comment: @Ramhound I am asking to catch ANY of them not all. :)

Comment: I have no idea you can always write one yourself. I deleted my comment because I thought I was mistaken, took another look, and I was looking at the changes to the wiki not the 3 year old .NET interface.  Furthermore if the .net interface current provides no way to catch an exception it wasn't desiged to do so.

Comment: If you really want such a tight control over the streaming process you will need to use other option instead of VLC... all options capable of this I know are commercial though...

Comment: @Yahia I see... Thanks for the input! Could you put our ideas like an answer please?

Comment: @Peretz Done... included 2 links for such (commercial) libraries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no option to achieve what you ask for when using VLC for the streaming part...

There are some commercial options allowing for tight control including error handling/notification:

IF a commercial library is an option take a look at http://www.visioforge.com/media-player-sdk-net.html

Another commercial option would be Leadtools MultIMedia SDK - see http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia.htm#+cp_playback

Comment: Does visioforge support rtsp, mms, rtp, http streaming protocols?

Comment: @Peretz IIRC rtsp, mms, http is supported... whether rtp is supported I am not sure... but drop them an email or download the free trial and see for yourself... IF you need a library that can do rtmp you can checkout http://www.broccoliproducts.com/softnotebook/rtmpclient/rtmpclient.php